# User friendly URLs in MVC with java-scripting

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Following code is used in `Route.config` file to successfully route users to `search` action method inside `Home` controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "search",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{inpSearch}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "search", inpSearch = "" }
    );
```

`search` action method code inside `Home` controller:

```
public ActionResult search(string inpSearch)
{
    var a = (from i in db.Items
             where i.ItemName.Contains(inpSearch) ||
             i.Category.Name.Contains(inpSearch) ||
             i.Brand.Name.Contains(inpSearch)
             select i).ToList();
    return View(a);
}
```

For user-friendly URLs, I used following javaScript:

```
$('#inpSearch').on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("search", "Home")/'
    var url = baseUrl + $('#inpSearch').val();
        window.location.href = url;                    
    }
})
```

As you can see I need to pass `inpSearch` string as a parameter to this `search` action method inside `Home` controller. Not sure how'd I do that.

User-friendly URL (i.e., /Home/search/car) for an example is working all well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using paramters as

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { paramName1 = paramValue1 })
```

OR

```
window.location.href ="/Home/search?inpSearch="+$('#inpSearch').val()
```

Comment: but where? inside javascript?

Comment: Well done mate. Second one worked all well. Thanks a lot.